# Way to write vhost for same subdomain across multiple domains?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I've got several domains setup in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

I need to setup webmail.domain*.com for each one. I can do this with individual vhost files for each, but is there a way to write a wildcard vhost to be caught by all domains?

Also, the same directory should be served by all webmail.*.com requests.

Comment: There are actually quite a few non-programming questions on Stack.

Comment: Indeed, merely making an observation :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) allows wildcards

Comment: I believe that's what my solution below employs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Despite my mean~ness, check out [Apache's vhosts documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) looks like the answer is not.  You need a FQDN, not a globbing character.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, here's what worked for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName webmail.domain.com
    ServerAlias webmail.*
    DocumentRoot /path/to/webmail
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```